# How should I store salmon en croute?

Tags: storage, salmon

I've half a pound of salmon en croute (made from [this](https://www.epicurious.com/recipes/member/views/gordon-ramsays-salmon-en-croute-5e091749fb26eb0008988566) recipe) left over from dinner this evening. I've never dealt with pastry encrusted salmon, so I'm not sure of storage best practices. I'd like to store it for approximately 12 hours, preferably in a way that preserves the puff pastry's stable, yet light, texture. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, storing it in the fridge is the only option, but it will hardly taste as before. **Storing it uncovered will make the pastry super dry afterwards** (at least when I stored it my first times), and covering it with a plastic film might make it a bit soggy (the pastry).

I'd recommend storing it in a lunchbox (or **with a plastic film, AND inside a lunchbox** if you can). I think it will preserve as max as possible the texture and taste but... don't expect too much. Salmon en croute has to be eaten recently made! (from my experience and recipes at least).

Comment: I ended up doing just what you've suggested here; it's not as good as last night, but the texture was preserved much better than I expected!

Comment: I'm super glad to hear that! Salmon by itself is not perfect for the next day, but pastry is a bit tricky. I'm happy for you! I hope you enjoyed it! @JohnBeverley

Answer (score 1):

You will obviously need to refrigerate.  If it is only 12-hours, I would cool, then leave it uncovered in your refrigerator, or maybe a loose draping of plastic.  For longer storage, I would wrap well and freeze.  Reheat in a 425-450F (218 - 232C) oven until just warm in the center (test with a cake tester by inserting into thickest part, wait 5- 10 sec., and touch to your lip). The pastry should come back, but probably not to its original glory.